# Send mail using SQL Server

Tags: email, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to send an email from a Trigger, on SQL Server 2008 . The data of the email will be, just a plain hardcoded text.
When user clicks on a trigger button from application my sp needs to send mail to specified users.
(Do i need to specify the users somewhere?)

Can someone provide some sample code on how to do this, please?

I've not set up any SQL mail and stuff, so I'm guessing it's built in.

Comment: Why do you want to send email via a stored procedure instead of the application code?

Comment: @DanGuzman we are trying to fetch more data into DB mail and i have some data in another table as well

Comment: "I am trying to send an email from a Trigger," - that's a really bad idea.

Comment: You need a full tutorial on DB Mail, there are plenty [online](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1100/setting-up-database-mail-for-sql-server/). [so] is really not the place for this.

Comment: @MitchWheat I have a sneaking suspicion that "trigger" just means a button on the screen. I hope....

Comment: "When user clicks on a trigger button from application" - then send the email from your application! Connect to a SMTP server...

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface, yes trigger is a button on screen in my application and thanks for the links .. it helps to get idea about DB mail

Comment: Thanks @MitchWheat, unfortunately my requirement is to Send mails from DB. so i cant use SMTP server in application

Comment: "unfortunately my requirement is to Send mails from DB" - that is a stupid requirement!

Answer (score 0):

like you set first you need to configure you SQL instance

> Permissions
> You must be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role to
> use the Send Test E-Mail dialog box. Users who are not members of the
> sysadmin fixed server role can test Database Mail using the
> sp_send_dbmail procedure.
>
> Procedure Using Object Explorer in SQL Server Management Studio,
> connect to an instance of SQL Server Database Engine where Database
> Mail is configured, expand Management, right-click Database Mail, and
> then select Send Test E-Mail. If no Database Mail profiles exist, a
> dialog prompts the user to create a profile and opens the Database
> Mail Configuration Wizard.
>
> In the Send Test E-Mail from dialog box, in the Database Mail Profile
> box select the profile you want to test.
>
> In the To box, type the e-mail name of the recipient of the test
> e-mail.
>
> In the Subject box, type the subject line for the test e-mail. Change
> the default subject to better identify your e-mail for
> troubleshooting.
>
> In the Body box, type to body of the test e-mail. Change the default
> subject to better identify your e-mail for troubleshooting.
>
> Select Send Test E-Mail to send the test e-mail to the Database Mail
> queue.
>
> Sending the test e-mail opens the Database Mail Test E-Mail dialog
> box. Make a note of the number displayed in the Sent e-mail box. This
> is the mailitem_id of the test message. Select OK.
>
> On the Toolbar select New Query to open a Query Editor window. Run the
> following T-SQL statement to determine the status of the test e-mail
> message:
>
> SQL
>
> Copy SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_allitems  WHERE mailitem_id =  ;

[click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/database-mail-sending-test-email?view=sql-server-ver15) to see the documentation

here is the sintaxis to use it.

Syntax

Copy

```
sp_send_dbmail [ [ @profile_name = ] 'profile_name' ]  
    [ , [ @recipients = ] 'recipients [ ; ...n ]' ]  
    [ , [ @copy_recipients = ] 'copy_recipient [ ; ...n ]' ]  
    [ , [ @blind_copy_recipients = ] 'blind_copy_recipient [ ; ...n ]' ]  
    [ , [ @from_address = ] 'from_address' ]  
    [ , [ @reply_to = ] 'reply_to' ]   
    [ , [ @subject = ] 'subject' ]   
    [ , [ @body = ] 'body' ]   
    [ , [ @body_format = ] 'body_format' ]  
    [ , [ @importance = ] 'importance' ]  
    [ , [ @sensitivity = ] 'sensitivity' ]  
    [ , [ @file_attachments = ] 'attachment [ ; ...n ]' ]  
    [ , [ @query = ] 'query' ]  
    [ , [ @execute_query_database = ] 'execute_query_database' ]  
    [ , [ @attach_query_result_as_file = ] attach_query_result_as_file ]  
    [ , [ @query_attachment_filename = ] query_attachment_filename ]  
    [ , [ @query_result_header = ] query_result_header ]  
    [ , [ @query_result_width = ] query_result_width ]  
    [ , [ @query_result_separator = ] 'query_result_separator' ]  
    [ , [ @exclude_query_output = ] exclude_query_output ]  
    [ , [ @append_query_error = ] append_query_error ]  
    [ , [ @query_no_truncate = ] query_no_truncate ]   
    [ , [ @query_result_no_padding = ] @query_result_no_padding ]   
    [ , [ @mailitem_id = ] mailitem_id ] [ OUTPUT ]
```

[click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to se the documetnation how to use.

Comment: Thanks @raul saucedo, this solution helps to enable mail configuration